# Any decent table CSS/layout for an admin control panel?

Tags: html, css

Since I'm not a web designer, it is difficult for me to design an admin control panel using CSS. More specifically, I have difficulties with designing data tables. Tables should contain: filters, sorting, items per page, displaying from/to/of, pagination.

Any good samples around how an ideal data table should look like? How should I approach designing an admin control panel?

Comment: you should learn css. It's not too hard and also, tables are bad when it comes to designing. divs and spans are good.

Comment: It also depends on what kind of design you want.

Comment: Lots of "developers" are terrible ([turrible](http://www.hark.com/clips/tkrqyfszkp-terrible)) at design. Designers, however, are usually pretty good at it.

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Envisioning-Information-Edward-R-Tufte/dp/0961392118/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321618202&sr=1-6) could be useful.

Comment: @zzlawlzz Tables are bad for layout, but excellent for tabular data.

Comment: zzlawlzz, duh!  What I did was post a bunch of resources links, thought that might be a little more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are still looking for the answer. But I found your question through Google. The following link helped me a lot:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/10/05/10-free-css-and-html-admin-and-backend-templates/

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I too had trouble while designing data tables till I found [datatables by Allan Jardine](http://datatables.net/). It's really cool with lots of features like inline editing, ajax and jsonp. It has great support forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

Spend less time working about the design part of your admin panels with [themeforest](http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates) admin templates. It cost money but whats a little bit of money compared to spending weeks trying to code up a beautiful admin panel. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**The most important thing is to think about the admin from the user's perspective.**

A common mistake is to design panel based on how the application is designed. Use terminology and micro-copy that mirror the task the user wants to engage in.  For example, a user wants to "add a page" or "edit a calendar event". Admin panels often have menu items like "modules" that are unintuitive to those that didn't build the application.

**Subtly can go a long way.**

Another common mistake to make headings and accents to big and too bright.
You can get color theme ideas from http://kuler.adobe.com

**Avoid Centering.**

It usually looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

The [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) plugin is an awesome plugin for displaying tables.Check it out.